# securing laravel api in angular

Tags: angular, laravel

I have this auth.interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler } from "@angular/common/http";
import { TokenService } from "../shared/token.service";

@Injectable()

export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private tokenService: TokenService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        const accessToken = this.tokenService.getToken();
        req = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
            }
        });
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

it is called in app.module.ts and other module.ts file

```
import { AuthInterceptor } from './shared/auth.interceptor';

  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
```

but i can access all the laravel apis without token

> Calling api:

```
this.http.post(this.baseUrl+'api/auth/load-data', formData).subscribe(result  => {
  this.lists=result;
  },(error) => {
});
```

I want to secure my laravel api

Comment: The securing needs to happen on the Laravel side.

Answer (score 0):

have you uesed laravel passport?
with that package you can secure your laravel apis

Comment: Serif: i'm using jwt, i used this link : https://www.positronx.io/laravel-angular-token-based-authentication-with-jwt/ for laravel : https://www.positronx.io/laravel-jwt-authentication-tutorial-user-login-signup-api/

Answer (score 0):

You should use the passport package in order to secure your APIs, this is the doc from the Laravel website:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport

I think its straight forward

Comment: i'm using jwt, i used this link : https://www.positronx.io/laravel-angular-token-based-authentication-with-jwt/, for laravel : https://www.positronx.io/laravel-jwt-authentication-tutorial-user-login-signup-api/